# Find a simple formula of k numbers which gives output a number not among these k numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-fields

This question just came to my mind while thinking. I just wanted to know if it is even possible. Anyway, the question goes as follows.

You are given k numbers $a_{i}$ (k < n) from 1 to n.

Your job is to give a simple formula represented as a function f($a_{1}, a_{2}, .., a_{k}$) which gives a number N $\in$ {1, 2, .., n} such that N $\neq$ $a_{i}$ for any i $\in$ {1, 2, .., k}

My approaches(which obviously have failed :P) :

1. ($\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i})$ % n + 1
2. ($\prod_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}$) % n + 1
3. (xor all of them) % n + 1
4. (and all of them) % n + 1 && (or all of them) % n + 1

I tried above approaches because they are similar to Euclid's proof that primes are infinite. This question seems to be related to abstract algebra, but I am still learning it so pardon me if I may have made a dumb mistake.

By "simple" I mean operations that can be performed in O(1) like +, -, x, /, xor, |, &, ...

Comment: A function certainly exists, I think what you are asking for is a (simple) formula.

Comment: Please use MathJax for the typos...We cannot make any sense otherwise....

Comment: I have edited it, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2):

You can do $f(K) = \min\{\{1,\dots,n\} \setminus K\} $ where $K=\{a_1,\dots\}$.

Comment: This will surely work, but I wanted something that can be written as a simple formula like the ones mentioned above.

Comment: @Jenil I thought this one was pretty simple. What operations do you allow?

Comment: Like the ones we can compute in O(1), like +, -, /, xor, |, &, ...

Comment: Do you have a machine that can add two numbers with 3928 digits in $O(1)$? (I know what you mean, just wanted to point out that it's harder to express).

Comment: @Jenil you could implement my function by taking the smallest bit of $\sum_{i\le n} 2^i - \sum_i 2^{a_i}$. If you can have the same number multiple times you can use "or" instead of plus.

Comment: @ThomasAhle, the problem in your solution is that it is not in the range {1, 2, .., n}. We have to still prove that even by taking modulo, we will get unique number not equal to $a_{i}$